# Does it make sense to allow IList parameter to be null or throw exception if null?

Tags: c#, collections, notnull

Here's what I came accross yesterday. I'm wondering what is the best practise here. I can make an instance of this class like this or parameter can be null coming from other places:

```
CustomItemsSourceDialogViewModel itemsSource = new CustomItemsSourceDialogViewModel();
itemsSource.Initialize(null); // I get nullReferenceException
```

Here's the mentioned class definition:

```
public class CustomItemsSourceDialogViewModel
{
  public void Initialize(IList<string> items)
  {
    // it doesn't make sense to allow parameter items to be null
    // it only makes sense to allow not null items collection
    // so we can operate on it.
    // if items is null we get system.nullReferenceException
    if (items.Count > 0)
      // aggregate is a system.linq static method
      this.ItemsSource = items.Aggregate((x, y) => x + "\r\n" + y);
  }
}
```

I prefer to keep my collections / lists not null. In other words collections should have a default value of empty collections. This way developer or user won't get that nasty NullReferenceException.

Regarding list parameter to a method, should I throw exception and notify the user when parameter is null:

```
public void Initialize(IList<string> items)
{
  if( items == null )
    throw new Exception("Parameter items is null. It should be a valid list.");
  ...
```

The other solution would be to check if it's not null:

```
public void Initialize(IList<string> items)
{
  if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
    this.ItemsSource = items.Aggregate((x, y) => x + "\r\n" + y);
 }
```

But checking always if not null seems a bit akward.

Comment: This is a *fashion sense* question, and depends what level you are writing this for, also it touches on *common sense*. If its exceptional that it is `null` then you throw an `ArgumentNullException`. Does the user expect it to be `null` here? Does ignoring this `null` have any significant impacts? Low level apis are heavily validated because they are heavily tested and need consistent results, high level mashed together code tends to have a bit more leeway. But it still comes back to the original point, is it exceptional?

Comment: I agree with the above, it depends how important it is that ItemsSource has values. You could simply do: if( items == null ) return; or if( items == null ) this.ItemsSource = new List<string>(). This would allow your execution to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to what TheGeneral and Will wrote - you don't ever want to see a `NullReferenceException` in production code.

What you need to do is decide if a null `IList` is expected to be passed to this method, and more importantly, if you can handle such cases is a way that won't break the business logic.
If the answer to both of these questions is "no", then you should throw an [ArgumentNullException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=netframework-4.8) - since this exception conveys the problem in the most precise way - the method expects the argument to not be null:

```
public void Initialize(IList<string> items)
{
    if( items is null ) // requires c# 7 or higher
    { 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items));
    }

    // rest of the code here
}
```

However, if your business logic can carry on without that `IList`, and a `null` is expected to be sent to this method, then you should handle that case inside the method, and not throw an exception - **Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances** - so if a null `IList` have the same effect as an empty `IList` and is expected to be passed into the method - it can't be considered exceptional and therefor shouldn't trigger an exception thrown.

```
public void Initialize(IList<string> items)
{
    // just a shorter way for the same condition - requires c# 6 or higher
    if (items?.Any() ?? false)
    {
        this.ItemsSource = Items.Aggregate((x, y) => x + "\r\n" + y);
    } // I like to always use code blocks for conditions etc'. I find it more readable.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this well elaborated answer. It depends on the business logic I guess.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should think from the perspective of: Is this a complete deal breaker or not? If it is then it makes sense to throw an exception at this point as it prevents further action, however a good practice is to stay away from exceptions as far as possible, unless as mentioned it is a show stopper.

In your case (which I understand to be a wrapper around specific list functionality) why do you not have a default list value initialized inline like this and have users add single items or params. Or you can finally check for null if it is not a deal breaker.

```
public List<string> ItemSource { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```